# Failed to parse the json response

Tags: android, json

Json response should look like :

> "{\"syncrequest\":{\"user\":{\"@xmlns:xsi\":\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\",\"active\":\"true\",\"basedataset\":\"false\"},\"syncversion\":\"89\",\"syncdata\":[{\"operation\":\"INSERT
>   OR
>   REPLACE\",\"table\":\"WSInformation\",\"rows\":[{\"WS_ID\":\"71\",\"WS_ParentOwn\":null,\"WS_Notes\":\"Notes\\"for\\"VistaStore
>   Fleet\\"save\",\"CC_ID\":\"1\",\"Record_Instance\":\"1\",\"Record_LastModified\":\"2013-11-26T07:51:35.203\"}]}]}}"

Response coming from server with a string format.    When i convert the above string in json format using

```
       JsonObject jObject =new JsonObject(string);
```

its getting error  like **unterminated character** in string.

Can any body help me out for above problem.

Thanks In advance

**Edited :**

The response coming from server is in the form  of  input stream .

So, I used to convert the inputstream to string using the function  :

```
     IOUtils.readStream(instream);
```

Then the response string should like :

string  **response** =

> "{\"syncrequest\":{\"user\":{\"@xmlns:xsi\":\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\",\"active\":\"true\",\"basedataset\":\"false\"},\"syncversion\":\"89\",\"syncdata\":[{\"operation\":\"INSERT
>   OR
>   REPLACE\",\"table\":\"WSInformation\",\"rows\":[{\"WS_ID\":\"71\",\"WS_ParentOwn\":null,\"WS_Notes\":\"Notes\\"for\\"VistaStore
>   Fleet\\"save\",\"CC_ID\":\"1\",\"Record_Instance\":\"1\",\"Record_LastModified\":\"2013-11-26T07:51:35.203\"}]}]}}"

By using the below function to form the json object,I removing the double quotes.

res = response.substring(1, response.length() - 1);

and removing double quotes with in the string using the below function.

res = response.replace("\\"", "\"");

Comment: post your http connetion code

Comment: Why are you escaping the ticks? The parser cannnot handle this, as this is no valid JSON.

Comment: yes, +1 on this, I don't use "\" on my JSON and all is fine

Comment: Who is in charge of that server?

Comment: In iOS platform , json is processing. They are using the technique of JSON serialization. In android platform only, its not processing even we are doing modifications.

Comment: If you want I can show you how I do JSON in my android app. I swear JSON is working on Android (or else I think we would have hear about it). But you' re right, it is easier to use it on iOS, I had to write 'models' of the object.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use JsonObject in conversion.

```
     JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(response);
     JSONArray jArray = jObject.getJSONArray("syncrequest");
```

import this org.json.JSONObject;

not com.google.gson.JsonObject;

Comment: well import JSONArray too :)

Comment: we are importing all necessarry importing. Here problem is when string contains double quotes , then its parse to fail json response.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not a valid JSON-object.

Comment: Maybe you have to specify something like this befor reading stream - setContentType("application/json") ?